# Is the MySQL command $myconnection->disconnect(); required in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

Is it required that I call the MySQL command 
`$myconnection->disconnect();` before exiting my Perl scripts? I've read somewhere that it's not necessary, but I want to be sure.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the DBI method? If so, read the docs: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#disconnect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not required. The connection will close naturally when your script exits.

Generally speaking, `$dbh->disconnect()` is only required in a few very specific situations. Most of the time, you can rely on the connection being closed when the script exits, or when all copies of the handle have gone out of scope.